# Open a new window and change its parent's content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for a way (in pure JS and / or jQuery) to open a link from a parent page A in a new window B and then changing the contents (or the url) of page A.
I can't control the HTML of B since it's owned by a third-party.

Something like that, in page A's sources:

```
$("#linkId").click(function(){
    //...invoke the window.open using #link.id's href
    //change contents of page A
});
```

Comment: You going right, replace the comments with the code and it will work.

Comment: Ehm... yeah, the code could be useful :)

Answer (score 0):

[**PLUNKER**](http://plnkr.co/edit/aqokKhyGn0oDzYNzYwTW?p=preview)

There's an easier way to change iframe src, it only involves HTML, no JS.

Notice the anchor to example.com. Basically all you need to do is the following:

- Add a name attribute to the iframe (I always have id and name the same)
- On the anchor, you change the target attribute value to the value of the iframe's name value.
- So in this demo the part inside {{{...}}} is the trick. The brackets are added for emphasis do not include them into the code to use.

  `<a href="http://example.com" {{{target="site"}}}>Example.com</a>`

  `<iframe id="site" {{{name="site"}}} src="/" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0"></iframe>`

In addition to that trick, I've added a function `changeSrc()`. Test it by typing a URL in the text input.

**Note:** Dyn-Web has a framebuster, so if you try to put it in the iframe, it should redirect you to the site. Some sites (like Google and Yahoo) are not open at all to iframes.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't fit the case. The destination I want is not an iFrame, it's a brand new page.

Comment: When you said parent page, I naturally thought of an iframe, my bad. So you want to open another sight from an anchor...but I'm not sure what you mean by >> ...to open a link from a parent page A in a new window B...<< >>...and then changing the contents (or the url) of page A.<< What are the contents of A changing *from* and changing *to*?

Comment: Examples of these contents are a single DIV, or the entire page A. I'd like to react after the opening of window B has been invoked.

Comment: I'm sorry, that doesn't make any sense...you want arbitrary content from page A (that you own) to *react* after you open page B (that you don't own). Ok, here is where there is a failure to communicate: *react*. Define *react* in the context of page A and page B. *React* is not a standard Event, nor is it a term I'm familiar with.

Comment: Rereading OP...Did you want to clone page B? As in copy page B and place it in page A? Do you want to change page A's content or is it URL? Content of page A is different than the URL of page A. Content is inside page A, like text, images, video, audio, etc. The URL of page A is it's location `http://lost.com/pageA.html`